# Detect broken link for Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am coding a discord bot command to embed an image from a subreddit. I am using the `praw` module for this. Some links that are scraped, however, don't end in an image extension, so it doesn't embed properly. For these, I simply want to link to the title and add a thumbnail. How can I do this?

Here is the code I am using:

Scraping:

```
def getTopMemes():
    reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id = 'id', 
                        client_secret = 'secret', 
                        user_agent = 'agent')

    titles = [submission.title for submission in reddit.subreddit("dankmemes").top("day", limit = 30)]
    urls = [submission.url for submission in reddit.subreddit("dankmemes").top("day", limit=30)]
    ran = random.randint(0,len(titles))
    return titles[ran], urls[ran]
```

Bot command:

```
@bot.command()
async def meme(ctx):
    title, url = getTopMemes()
    embed1 = discord.Embed(title = title)
    embed1.set_image(url = url)
    await ctx.channel.send(embed = embed1)
```

Resulting embed:

[image]

Comment: Could you include the error message if there is one?

Comment: There is no error, it's just an empty embed, but I can add a picture, one sec.

Comment: If I'm understanding the issue correctly, you could use something like regex to look for a .png/.jpg/.jpeg at the end of a url. If that isn't there, add it.

Comment: @Kelo That is a good idea. Is there any way I can use that as a condition in the list comprehension?

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the url has an image extension and then add it on if it doesn't

```
def ext_check(url):
  if re.search("(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)((\?+)?$|$)", url) == None:
    url += ".png"
  return url

urls = [ext_check(submission.url) for submission in reddit.subreddit("dankmemes").top("day", limit=30)]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however I tried this on a regex checker online, and it said invalid regex.

Comment: Ah ok, lemme check it

Comment: @DapperDuck Try that

Comment: This should work, however I found a shorter solution. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I added the following condition to the list comprehension and it worked: 
`if submission.url[-4:] in ('.jpg', 'jpeg', '.gif', 'gifv', '.png')`

Full comprehension

```
titles = [submission.title for submission in reddit.subreddit("dankmemes").top("day", limit=50) if submission.url[-4:] in ('.jpg', 'jpeg', '.gif', 'gifv', '.png')]
urls = [submission.url for submission in reddit.subreddit("dankmemes").top("day", limit=50) if submission.url[-4:] in ('.jpg', 'jpeg', '.gif', 'gifv', '.png')]
```